# Expected Identifier '('

Tags: objective-c, compiler-errors

```
- (IBAction) SignUp:(id)sender;  {  //  Expected Identifier '('

    IBOutlet UITextField *Firstnamefield;
    IBOutlet UITextField *Lastnamefield;
    IBOutlet UITextField *emailfield;
    IBOutlet UITextField *agefield;
    IBOutlet UITextField *passwordfield:
    IBOutlet UITextField *reenterpasswordfield;
}
```

I need the semicolon by sender the coding is under .h view controller.

Comment: windows: ctrl + k, apple: cmd + k.  Highlight all your text and use that hotkey and someone will actually read this.

Comment: Xcode? Really, why the Xcode tag? And the IBAction one? This question has absolutely nothing to do with the IDE used nor with the return type of the method.

Comment: And why are you re-posting the **exact same question** some 26 minutes after having posted the original one???

Answer (score 1):

Don't put your code block in the .h. If your code has a block, but the declaration in the .h (as in `-(IBAction)SignUp:(id)sender;` and put the actual method (what you currently have minus that semicolon) in the .m.

Also, do do not want to put your IBOutlet variable declarations in a method. If you are creating a view when a button is pressed, then you would put them in the method for that button press, but when they are IBOutlet views like that you want to just declare them in the `@interface`.